# Get current environment

Tags: python, global-variables, environment-variables, scons

I know I can create a new *environment* in my SConstruct and, in some way, it works and the environment is passed on along the execution thread.

This is my Sconstruct:

```
env = Environment() 
env.SConscript('site_scons/environment.py', 'env')
Export('env')
```

This is environment.py

```
from SCons.Script import Import # Seems like it's not really needed
Import('env')
env = env.Clone() # NameError: name 'env' is not defined:
```

Interestingly enough, if I put a breackpoint *after* the `Clone` call, I can use the `env` object and the exception is raised *later*.

```
      5 env = env.Clone()
----> 6 import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

ipdb> env
<SCons.Script.SConscript.SConsEnvironment object at 0x2b3dad0>
ipdb> c
NameError: name 'env' is not defined:
```

Is there a proper way to acquire the current running Environment?

Please note that I need to use the environment object in a python module not just a SConscript.

Comment: Will this other Python module also be invoked by SCons? If so, you are doing it correctly and dont need to import the SCons.Script part. Try changing your Clone line to this: clonedEnv = env.Clone()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to explicitly `export` the env to be able to `import` it. See [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/x3186.html)
So, like

```
env = Environment(tools=['default', 'qt4'])
Export('env')
```

Comment: Using Export() will make it available to other SConscript files in the same project. It should also be mentioned that the Import() function will be needed in these other SConscript files. This can also be done using the export attribute of the SConscript() function.

Comment: Ok, but what if I need it in a python module. 
I'll edit the question to explain my point better.

Comment: A scons script is a python module, kinda